# I forgot what wallet is connected to an address. Is there anyway to figure out at least what wallet i used ?

Tags: wallet, client

I had to put in an address on a site in case of returns or what not. i use multiple wallets since i have multiple accounts. One of my first accounts received a return and i can not figure out what wallet i used. It is a web wallet which i have narrowed down to three possible sites. I found the address that the money was sent to but is there anyway to figure out what wallet just by using the address attached to the account? i have the public,private, and encrypted keys to each of the 3 wallets that i use. is there anyway to find it using one of those keys? ( **no i am not dumb enough to give my private key to anyone**)

Answer (score 1):

No, the address doesn't tell you anything about the service or account. The only way to find the payment is by checking each wallet.